# declare Object properties with same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In my object, there are several properties that values are all same and key is different

```
const arr: any = {
        Combo: ['state', 'command'],
       Extrahit: ['state', 'command'],
        Punish: ['frame', 'command', 'damage', 'range', 'hitframe'],
        standing: ['frame', 'command', 'damage', 'range', 'hitframe'],
        up: ['frame', 'command', 'damage', 'range', 'hitframe'],

    };
```

I wonder how I can simplify this declaration part.

What I found was to use iteration functions. but this way does not seems to fit my question.

I'm looking for way to improve code readabilty.

Is there any way I can do?

Comment: I think that you'll find trying to change the object to improve readability you're actually going to end up _reducing_ readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reusable variables to DRY up your code:

```
const stateValues = ['state', 'command']
const frameValues = ['frame', 'command', 'damage', 'range', 'hitframe'] 

const arr: any = {
        Combo: stateValues,
        Extrahit: stateValues,
        Punish: frameValues,
        standing: frameValues,
        up: frameValues,
    };
```